# How can one implement a rational function in frequency domain using integrators in time domain?

Tags: laplace-transform

There is a simple method to implement a rational function in frequency domain using integrators and feedback in time domain. Could somebody draw a nice picture and show which coefficient of the rational function belongs where in the time domain circuit?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please consider using MathJax to reformat this post in line with community norms.

Comment: @integrand -- I once did the effort to learn this and worked on it for an hour only to have my question in the end deleted.